# full calendar week view in horizontally

Tags: jquery, html

How can I covert the full calendar week view vertical mode to horizontal? Currently fullcalendar 1.5.4 provides days as column wise in week view. But I need a week calendar with days in row wise.(one week calendar, 2 week calendar, etc.)
Can you help me?
Thanks in advance